# DAG not taking the parameterzied message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a DAG that needs to do execute a Python opertaor and pass the resulting string as a message to PubsubPublish Operator.

My code below print messages perfectly but when I upload this DAG to airflow, it doesnot load. I think it is the structure of my DAG and that the pubsubpublish operator cannot read the parameter 'messages'

I tried using the message as a templated field, but that did not help too.

```
def download_yaml():
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
content_blob=blob.download_as_string()
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(content_blob)
return encoded_string

encoded_string = download_yaml()
messages = [
     {'data': b64encode(encoded_string)},

] 
print messages
dag= DAG('pubsub-message-docker', default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))
t2 = PubSubPublishOperator(project=project,topic=topic,task_id='publish-messages', messages=messages,dag=dag)

t1= PythonOperator(task_id='download_yaml_as_string',provide_context=True,python_callable=download_yaml,dag=dag)

t1.set_downstream(t2)
```

I am able to print the 'encoded string', however I need to pass encoded_string as a message in my pubsubpublish operator so that this gets published.

Comment: The indenting of the `download_yaml` function looks off. Is that how you have it on your python file? Or is that just the formatting in your post?

Also, are you able to provide some further information on the error you are getting? Is the DAG showing in the airflow UI? Or is it missing? And what errors are being shown in the logs? Thanks.

Comment: No i think its just here. Dont have any indent error on my python. Also the DAG does show in the UI but with a message that it does and master scheduler is unaware of its existence. The name of DAG shows up but with no options to execute or view the logs .So basically it isnt loading the DAG in airflow as it should. What i doubt is if this is the right wat to pass message to pubsubpublish operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could resolve it :)
The message must be passed to pubsubpublish operator like below:

messages={'data':("{{task_instance.xcom_pull(key='encoded_string',task_ids='download_yaml')}}")}

and then pass messages to parameter messages.
t2 = PubSubPublishOperator(project=project,topic=topic,task_id='publish-messages',messages=messages,dag=dag)

Best Regards
Sakshi

Answer (score 1):

Here is two points for your consider.
1. For exchange information between dag operators, Xcom should be more official way.

> XComs let tasks exchange messages, allowing more nuanced forms
>   of control and shared state. The name is an abbreviation of
>   “cross-communication”. ...... Any object that
>   can be pickled can be used as an XCom value, so users should make sure
>   to use objects of appropriate size.
>
> XComs can be “pushed” (sent) or “pulled” (received). .....
>
> Tasks call xcom_pull() to retrieve XComs, optionally applying filters
>   based on criteria like key, source task_ids, and source dag_id. ......

https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms

2. you python file may run and get unknown result as messages has not relationship with task t1. It is just initailized in the beginning by function download_yml. Though t1 call download_yml again, but the has do not change messages. Thus, T2 get messages only with initial value.  To solve it, you has to push messages in t1 to Xcom, and pull messages in t2 from Xcom.

Good luck.

WangYong

Comment: Thaks for your suggestion , the dag shows up in the UI now. however is failing.
def pull_function(**context): value=context['download_yaml_as_string'].xcom_pull(task_ids='publish-messages') t2 = PubSubPublishOperator(project=project,topic=topic,task_id='publish-messages', messages=pull_function,dag=dag) I am using this code, but this gives me an error that I cant pass function to parameter 'messages'. How can i pass this value?

Comment: Well. You has to push xcome in to create a xcom data in your T1 task and then pull it in your T2 task later. Besides, you has to use content["ti"].xcom_pull(key='publish-messages', value=. format to push you data.

Comment: well according to the document : https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms, I am returing a value so I am automatically pushing this value. Do i need to explicitly push it also? I am pulling like this: 
def pull_function(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    value2=ti.xcom_pull(key=None,task_ids='download_yaml',format=string)
However this is with error. Also how to i pass it to messages parameter:
t2 = PubSubPublishOperator(project=project,topic=topic,task_id='publish-messages', messages=???,dag=dag)
Hope you can help me with this. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. You can push the xcom data in two mode: default(implicitly) or by key,value(explicitly).  For the second mode, it is like .     kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='value from pusher 1', value = messages) . Note: there is lots of useful dag examples in airflow. You can learn from them. to open them, you just need set airflow.cfg --> load_examples = True  .  if you found my answer useful, pls vote it.

Comment: Thanks Yong Wong.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the DAG in the UI, but are getting the error you mentioned in your comment (master scheduler is unaware of its existence), then I'd suggest taking a quick look into the scheduler first! Ensure the scheduler has access to your DAGs, and then try restarting the scheduler. When you have that error... you will see the DAG in the web UI, but wont be able to run it or view it's logs.

As for your other question regarding passing messages to the PubSubPublishOperator, I believe that should work fine!

Comment: I tried changing {'data': b64encode(encoded_string)} to  {'data': b64encode('hello')} and the DAG appeared just fine. However like you said in the logs it did not say it published something to PubSub.

Comment: I am trying to use Xcom now.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share a solution for when there's nested templated values that need to be filled, such as when the message's payload ("data") is json. The built-in PubSubPublishOperator in Airflow v1.10.x doesn't support filling nested values, so I created a custom operator. Side benefit: you can pass in normal dictionary/string values, without having to worry about encoding:

````
import json

from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1


class BetterPubSubPublishOperator(BaseOperator):
    """Publish Pub/Sub messages to a topic.

    Allows for templated values to be filled in nested json messages,
    which won't get filled using the official `PubSubPublishOperator`.

    Args:
        project: Name of the project where the `topic` resides.
        topic: Name of the Pub/Sub topic to publish to.
        messages: A list of dictionaries, where each dictionary reflects a message to be published.
                  Each message must define one or both of "data" and/or "attributes" keys.

    Example:
        ```
        with DAG(
            "some_dag",
            schedule_interval=None,
            max_active_runs=1,
            catchup=False,
        ) as dag:
            t_publish_pubsub = BetterPubSubPublishOperator(
                task_id="publish_pubsub",
                project="your-project",
                topic="your-topic-name",
                messages=[
                    {
                        "data": {
                            "messageId": str(uuid4()),
                            "publishTime": "{{ ti.start_date }}",
                            "youKey1": "key1 value",
                            "youKey2": "key2 value",
                        },
                        "attributes": {"labelKey1": "label1 value", "labelKey2": "label2 value"},
                    }
                ],
            )

        ```

    """

    template_fields = ("project", "topic", "messages")
    ui_color = "#0273d4"

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, project: str, topic: str, messages: List[Dict], *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.project = project
        self.topic = topic
        self.messages = messages

    @staticmethod
    def publish(project: str, topic: str, messages: List[Dict], **context) -> None:
        client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        topic_path = client.topic_path(project, topic)

        for message in messages:
            raw_data = message.get("data")
            if isinstance(raw_data, (dict, list)):
                data = json.dumps(raw_data).encode("utf-8")
            elif isinstance(raw_data, str):
                data = raw_data.encode("utf-8")
            elif raw_data is None:
                data = b""
            else:
                raise TypeError(
                    f"Message's 'data' value is not an acceptable type. "
                    f"Type is {type(raw_data)}, but must be one of dict, list, str, or None"
                )

            if "attributes" in message:
                attrs = message.get("attributes", {})

            future = client.publish(topic=topic_path, data=data, **attrs)
            messade_id = future.result()  # blocking operation
            logging.info(
                f"Published the following message to topic {topic_path}:\n"
                f"{message}\n"
                f"The messade_id is {messade_id}"
            )

    def execute(self, context):
        # Export context to make it available for callables to use.
        airflow_context_vars = context_to_airflow_vars(context, in_env_var_format=True)
        self.log.debug(
            "Exporting the following env vars:\n%s",
            "\n".join(["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in airflow_context_vars.items()]),
        )
        os.environ.update(airflow_context_vars)

        self.publish(
            project=self.project, topic=self.topic, messages=self.messages, **context
        )
````

Note: uses pubsub v1 client, but can easily be updated for a newer version.